# How to go to first line of the file in php?

Tags: php, file

I am reading the file and getting the particular line if there is a match for the searched string. There are bunch of strings to be searched which are stored in a array. I cant be opening the file every time when i loop through the array to get the string. But want to go to the first line of the file and start searching again. The file contains around 15k lines. If i open the file every time(inside the loop) its working fine. but if the open the file outside the loop. Only the first matched string line is returned.

```
$scheme_code = 
array("106212","112422","114239","104685","100122","118191","131666");
foreach($scheme_code as $searchthis) {

        $handle = @fopen("myfile", "r"); 


        //DONT WANT TO DO THE ABOVE LINE FOR EVERY ITERATION

        if ($handle)
        {
            //echo "handle open"."<br>";
            while (!feof($handle))
            {

                $buffer = fgets($handle,4096);
                if(strpos($buffer, $searchthis) !== FALSE){
                    $matches[] = $buffer;
                }                       
            }               
        }       
    }
```

But want to do something like this

```
$handle = @fopen("Myfile", "r"); 
foreach(){
   // inside foreach 
   //go to the first line of the file
}
fclose($handle);
```

**EDIT** - I tried rewind(). I got the notice "**rewind(): stream does not support seeking**"

Comment: Please have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.rewind.php

Comment: When i use rewind, it says file doesnt support seeking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function which will give you complete array of lines and after that you can match line by line without using your IO resource everytime by `fopen`.

```
<?php

$linesArray = file("/path/to/your/file.txt"); 
foreach($linesArray as $line){
   // do the stuff or matching you want to perform line by line on $line
}
```